# при запуске выдает ошибку Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getInt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-sqlite

ClientDBHelper

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class ClientDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_NAME = "info.db";
    private static String DB_PATH = "C://Users//User//Desktop//project//app//src//main//assets//info.bd";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;

    public ClientDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        else
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;

        copyDataBase();

        this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    public void updateDataBase() throws IOException {
        if (mNeedUpdate) {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
                dbFile.delete();

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                copyDBFile();
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0)
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            mNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    public void putInformation(String name, int age, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

DisplayList

```js
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DisplayList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        ClientDBHelper clientDBHelper = new ClientDBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = clientDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = clientDBHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);

        //cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Object object = new Object(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2));
            arrayList.add(object);
        }
        while
        (
                cursor.moveToNext()
        );
        clientDBHelper.close();

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы явно возвращаете null из getInformation.

Comment: это понятно, что нужно добавить getInformation, чтоб он возвращал данные из таблицы?